# Installing ipa file from itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, monaca

I'm developing an app in Monaca IDE. I've created the certificates and the provisioning profile surrely correct.
When trying to install the ipa file in iTunes, it stuck in "installing" doens't matter what I do.
Here is the print from iTunes:
[image]

Print From iPhone(4s):
[image]

Sometimes the name of the app is shown, but when I tap, it turn to "Installing" again. The app icons is always with that shadow like in the print above.

My OS is Windows 10 and the phone is an iPhone 4s with IOS 9.2.1

I've already read the similiar posts:

- iTunes not installing .ipa file
- App stuck on installing ipa from iTunes
- Installing IPA file from iOS app

Comment: I don't think this should be closed, but unfortunately I don't know the answer either.

Comment: What kind of build? Ad-Hoc, release, enterprise? What you describe appears to be a provisioning profile issue.

Comment: I've tested with ad-hoc and development build.

Comment: You may need to add your UDID of your iPhone to your Apple Developer Portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you have a developer acount you should not use Ad-Hoc you should use Development Deployment (make sure your device was registrate in your apple account devices)

[image: Select correct export [1]]

Second if are not sure use xcode provisioning generated.
Now remove your ipa in the list of apps in itunes button right and remove:

[image: Remove your app to reinstall]

Now drag and drop new ipa to this list, in iTunes go to apps in your device use apply and sync to remove the ipa, press install and apply and sync again.

Comment: Hi, Jose, Thanks for replying, but I can't use the xCode because i'm in Windows platform. I've already tried a development deployment, but unsuccessfully. I'm generating the ipa file from the Monaca IDE.

Comment: The ipa has a bundler id this bundler id has asociate devices and you only can run this ipas in this devices. Go to member center devices and add your uuid in your provisioning profile. You can get your uuid with itunes.

Comment: Jose, i was using an app to get my UDID, but this app gave me a wrong uuid. Now with the correct UDID it works perfectly. Thanks!